# Software for creating custom maps

Tags: windows, maps

I would like to build a custom map for a fictional city. I am searching for a software, to build the map with. I know that vectors software can do that, but I am wondering if something more WYSIWYG exists?

I don't want to use any base (Google maps or Open Street Maps), just a fresh one.

Thanks!

Comment: [WorldBuilding.SE] has many questions about map generator software; just browse its ['map' questions](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+map)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need a 2D map editor (something of geographic information system (GIS) type), you may try [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/).

QGIS is a suite of tools for graphical information systems which allows you to "create, edit, visualise, analyse and publish geospatial information" for real or imaginary locations.

It is free, gratis & Open Source, and cross platform.

Screenshot (real world data):
[image]

If you actually need a 3D terrain editor / world builder, you may try the the following software:

- Vue (E-on software)
- Grome Editor
- World Machine
- WorldBuilder Pro

Answer (score -1):

Potentially Mapbox Studio or Scribble Maps may meet your needs. The former is more feature rich, but *can* cost more and might not be as easy to use. Both allow customization of the map down to removing streets, etc. Scribble Maps appears to allow more removal of layers than Mapbox but I am not for sure.