# Cartography: Software for creating high quality topographic maps

Tags: maps, printing, gis, openstreetmap

I’m looking for recommendation for (a) professional solution(s) for printing **large-scale high-quality topographic map** (e.g., topographic map for hiking like this [one](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geomart.com%2Fimages%2Fdigital%2Fdrg%2Fdrgplain.jpg&f=1) or large-scale city map like that [one](https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mappery.com%2Fmaps%2FOxford-City-Map-2.jpg&f=1)). I want to define my own style and be able to print large scale (let’s say 1:10000) paper maps on large formats (let’s say A0-A1). I’m not looking for making map tiles for web-based slippy maps. My source of data would be primarily OpenStreetMap, from which I would use either geofabrik shp or layers from a postgreSQL database using imposm/osm2pgsql. The others capabilities I’m looking for:

- can fill polygon with textural pattern instead of single color pattern
- can make labelling that follows the shape of the elements, such as curved labels along a curved river or a curved street.
- can include contour drawing (of elevation).
- output in vector format.
- can make it programmatically in order to be repeatable for many places.

From what I know, here are some options:

- Mapnik: currently the best solution I have.
- QGIS: But does it (well) support the printing of large maps? I’m also afraid that this would be poorly programmable. Yes I'm aware of this [post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/software-for-creating-custom-maps), but actually I know QGIS well and I know it is not an easy solution for producing large-scale topographic map programmatically unless there is a QGIS plugin or a framework based on QGIS dedicated for that.
- Mapserver: Following this tutorial, I could basically achieve what I want. But it remains a hard work to style the map-file. https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Rendering-OSM-data-on-Ubuntu-12.04

But are there some other options? Any feedbacks on this topic?

Comment: I found an useful resource: qgis style sheet (qml) for using with OSM data: https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/