# Custom Map making tools (Mapbox vs Scribblemaps or alternatives)

Tags: web-apps, maps, wysiwyg, gis, mapping

I noticed there is *one* similar questions to this (I provided [an answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/software-for-creating-custom-maps) based upon what I know already).

I am looking for recommendations for web map customization software, specifically comparing Mapbox, Scribblemaps and other alternatives.

I am looking for a tool that allows customization of all features on the map including removal of roads, water bodies, etc from the basemap (ie not just "hidden" but not appearing altogether on more detailed levels) as well as complete styling control (fonts, borders, markers).

My use case is a historical/literature map where I want all modern borders, modern terrain (i.e parks, irrigation, road outlines) removed yet retain the actual geography of the map (water, natural terrain, fully scalable areas). Making a map entirely from scratch would probably be counterintuitive for my purposes. A GIS tool may not offer the styling/customization I am looking for nor as shareable/collaborative as a web map. Preferably this tool would allow visual manipulation (via WYSIWYG editor) as well as changing by coding. The map created also needs to be embedded and connected with another application if necessary.

So far I've only discovered two tools that can do this: **Mapbox Studio** and **Scribble Maps**.
Is there any other software tools that can accomplish these purposes asides from the two aforementioned? Out of these two (or any others you know of) which one(s) would you recommend for what reason?
Does one tool do better at a particular use case than another?